# SSIS: How to set the value of initial catalog throught script taske

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ssis

i am looping through my connections:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Dts.Connections.Count; x++)
{

    switch (Dts.Connections[x].Name.ToString())
    {
        case "m":

           for (int z = 0; z < Dts.Connections[x].Properties.Count; z++)
            {
                      if ( Dts.Connections[x].Properties[n].Name = "Initial Catalog"){
                Dts.Connections[x].Properties[n].SetValue(object o, object value);}
            }

            break;
    }                  
}
```

above is as far as i have gotten, the signature of setvalue is (Object o, Object value)

Comment: What's the question? And how does that relate to the code you posted?

Comment: when i find the property called "Initial Catalog", how do i set its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation of `SetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtsproperty.setvalue.aspx), the first parameter is the object on which you want to set the property and the second is the property value. So it should be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Dts.Connections.Count; i++)
{
    var connection = Dts.Connections[i];
    if (connection.Name == "m")
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < connection.Properties.Count; j++)
        {
            var property = connection.Properties[j];

            if (property.Name == "Initial Catalog")
                property.SetValue(connection, "some value");
        }
    }
}
```

Or with LINQ:

```
var connection = Dts.Connections.Cast<ConnectionManager>()
                                .First(cm => cm.Name == "m");
var property = connection.Properties.Cast<DtsProperty>()
                                    .Single(p => p.Name == "Initial Catalog");
property.SetValue(connection, "some value");
```

(The `Cast()`s are necessary, because the collections are, sadly, not generic.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to setup a DTS Connection

```
ConnectionManager cn = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";
```